# Mono FSharpC error with Type Provider

Tags: compiler-errors, f#, mono, type-providers, f#-data

I have this code in `Yoghurt.Fruit.fs`

```
module Yoghurt.Fruit
 open FSharp.Data
 type Fruit = JsonProvider<"fruit.json">
 let fruit = Fruit.Load("fruit.json")
 let fruitExists name = fruit.Callouts |> Array.exists (fun el -> el.Name = name)
```

I am running this compile command in OSX with Mono
`fsharpc --nologo -r ../../fsharp-lib/Fhsarp.Data/FSharp.Data.dll Yoghurt.Fruit.fs -a -o:bin/Yoghurt.Fruit.dll`

I get this error

`* Assertion at threads.c:1360, condition 'internal' not met`

`Illegal instruction: 4`

(nb first ' before internal is actually ` edited here for formatting)

I have no idea what this error means and why I am getting it. I have a collection of `.fs` files that I am compiling in this way (to run tests against them - and then finally use them all in a `.fsx` file). In the main `.fsx` file I have this code

```
#r "/Users/philharvey/Documents/code/fsharp/fsharp-lib/Fhsarp.Data/FSharp.Data.dll"
open FSharp.Data
type Fruit = JsonProvider<"fruit.json">
let fruit = Fruit.Load("fruit.json")
let fruitExists name = fruit.Callouts |> Array.exists (fun el -> el.Name = name)
```

and this works just fine. I would really like to pull out this code into a module to be separately tested (there is other functionality besides `fruitExists` that I haven't listed because I have boiled my problem down to this).

Anyone have any insight?

*Edit*

result of `mono -V`

```
Mono JIT compiler version 3.0.10 ((no/eff4cb5 Sat Apr 13 19:24:30 EDT 2013)
Copyright (C) 2002-2012 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           normal
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notification:  kqueue
    Architecture:  x86
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug
    LLVM:          yes(3.2svn-mono)
    GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC)
```

`fsharpc` gives `F# Compiler for F# 3.0 (Open Source Edition)`

(and for extra info I am using this for tests `Mono.framework/Versions/3.0.10/bin/nunit-console4`

*Edit 2*

`FSharp.Data Version 1.1.5`

*Edit 3*

More information: I have just tested an `.fsx` through `fsharpi` and `fsharpc` using the `JsonProvider` as above. It works through `fsharpi` but not `fsharpc` (gives the same error above). I have also done a test with `fsharpc` using the template (basic) from here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2011/07/30/f-console-application-template.aspx. Gives the same error when the type provider is used.

Comment: please tell the mono version you're using

Comment: I have edited to this effect: short answer 3.0.10

Comment: Hmm, I have just upgraded to mono `3.2.1` and made sure I am on latest version of F# `1.1.9` and the problem has gone away. Was this just a bug that has now been fixed?

Comment: Do you still have a question or can this question be closed?

Comment: Pushed the answer into an 'answer' and set question to answered so it is clear what the resolution was. Happy to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just upgraded to `mono 3.2.1` and made sure I am on latest version of `F# 1.1.9` and the problem has gone away.